# Does Android support a default terminal application?

Tags: settings, terminal, default-applications

Considering that [KDE Plasma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LDUy.png) and Windows 11 do, and the availability of brilliant terminals like Termux, this seems like it would be an obvious feature, at least configurable via Developer Settings. However, I don't see any obvious method exposed via `com.android.settings`'s GUI.

Comment: That apps like Termux still work is only because they use some sort of "compatibility mode" for older apps. That is the reason why Termux isn't updated in Play Store - Google doesn't allow to use recent apps to use this compatibility mode anymore (apps now have to follow the Write xor execute rule). So form Google perspective terminal apps are insecure and outdated and some day they will stop working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, Android does not support a default terminal application.**

[According to AOSP](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/proto_logging/stats/enums/app/settings_enums.proto;l=2078;drc=c19c8ec6bb0d5455f8622e8bb43a1c4df3a7a168), categories that have default apps (as of Android 13):

- Browser app
- Emergency app<sup>1</sup>
- Digital assistant app
- Home app
- Phone app
- SMS app
- Caller ID & spam app<sup>2</sup>

A few reasons to consider why there are settings for default apps:

- Features that are considered core for common users, as well as used by other apps (browsing, calling, texting)
- User convenience to change when needed (home/launcher)
- Additional privileges to the selected app, or restrictions imposed by Android to the rest of the apps in the same category (caller ID, digital assistant, phone, SMS)

However, terminal apps are not (yet) considered for the above reasons, as observed that *there is no built-in terminal app even in common stock Android ROMs (including AOSP)*. It is also unlikely that there are multiple terminal apps installed that need to be restricted, or other apps that interact directly with a terminal app.

---

<sup>1 On AOSP but not observed on Google Pixel 3A (Android 12) and Samsung Galaxy M12 (Android 13)

2 Not on AOSP but observed on Google Pixel 3A (Android 12) and Samsung Galaxy M12 (Android 13)</sup>